# Does external HDD RAID closure exists not primarily for portability?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, raid, terminology

Is there such a class of hardware in which you can install multiple HDDs set up as RAID, while the unit maintains their ventilation and power consumption, independently of a computer?

External HDD enclosures often contain poor plugs that can easily disconnect if moved, I mean a class that is designed to be part of your home or office (however it is would be desirable if it can be moved easily when needed, too). (I expect it also not be a dock though, as I think it won't protect the HDDs, accept multiple ones, do raid and manifest as a 
box for transportation.)

I mean such a kind that would prioritize USB connectivity over other kinds (say, ethernet), in order to be used as simple external drives (in contrast to servers), and because most desktops have only one ethernet socket. But unlike external closures, one meant to be placed like a tower or a box, with a fix placement and own legs.

Comment: We really don't do product suggestions.  But you would need to look into NAS products.  One such product is `Drobo`.

Comment: @Ramhound, I edited my question, intended to be better worded! (I think it was misinterpreted, I'm not looking for individual products. It's like I'm looking for a device like 'steering wheel' but don't know if it exists and what it is called.)

Answer (score 4):

In general, the class of device you describe would be called [network-attached storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage), NAS for short; the specific use case you describe can be filled by any number of home- or small-business-grade devices of that type.

Comment: would it be different if I would want usb3 connectivity + raid capability only? (no ethernet)

Comment: FYI: I edited my question to express more accurately what I mean. (already +1) What I meant is ethernet is a secondary option, not a main concern.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's vanishingly unlikely that you will find RAID capability in anything not marketed as a NAS, and many, if not most, such devices offer USB connectivity as well as Ethernet.

Comment: can USB-enabled NAS be used as external drives? like choosing any kind of filesystem, USB booting...

Comment: Not usually -- but, per Carl B's answer below, there apparently exist devices which are exactly what you're looking for, rather than the "mostly" which a USB-capable NAS would be.

Answer (score 1):

There are such devices. Basicly they are multi hard drive enclosured with RAID.

An example is from icy dock[image: Icy dock].

It has not network port, but USB, 1394 and eSATA connection options and is idependent of the computer. It is meant more for desk top use, but can easily be transported.

There are many vendors but you could start by looking [Newegg icydock raid enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817198050)

As per some of your requirments, here are some parts of the spec:

> RAID Modes: JBOD, BIG (SPANNED), RAID0 (FAST), RAID1 (SAFE)
>
> RAID Setting: Rotray Switch
>
> Drive Cooling:  Quiet Sunon MAGLev Cooling Fan w/ Adjustable fan speed
>   VR control Aluminum body heat dispersion

Here is a five bay example:
[image: 5 bay]

Just to cover the bases in case someone does want portability, there are external RAID cases that utilize two 2.5" drives as well. Like the CRU ToughTech Duo 3SR 36020-3010-0100

[image: 2.5 rad enclosure]

Comment: I didn't know such equipment existed. Thanks for cluing me in!